# Datasets in for taxi/uber in Pakistan with spatio-temporal components

Tags: data-request, geospatial, traffic, asia

Where can I find datasets for Careem or Uber taxi trips in Pakistan, like e.g. the [Taxi & Limousine Commission Trip Record Data](http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/about/trip_record_data.shtml) in New York, for spatio temporal analysis?

Comment: Ask those companies yourself. They will probably refuse unless you are working on something PR-worthy like epidemiology.

Comment: Since you are asking for the dataset for a specific country, I am assuming that you might be looking at some policy related application. In that case, it would make sense to contact the company directly as @Emre suggested.